# It is possible to scroll a CollectionView with mouse click or scroll wheel on UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, collectionview

I'm using a `CollectionView` in my application and I wan't that `CollectionView` can be scrolled by the mouse click and/or scroll wheel.

I'm using Xamarin 4.4 and if it's possible, I need to do this with MVVM pattern.

There is the definition of my `CollectionView`

```
CollectionView v = new CollectionView()
            {
                SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single,
                ItemsLayout = new GridItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Horizontal),
                HeightRequest = 60,
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Always,
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Never,
                FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight, 
            };
```

Thank's for your help !

Comment: I test your code in my VS here is running GIF https://imgur.com/a/mq4iZ6D, I cannot scroll it by clicking the scrollbar, when I use scroll wheel, this content of the Collectionview will small up and down movement ,my xamarin forms version is 4.3.0.908675, other package version you can refer to this thread. https://imgur.com/a/ptAj2WD

Comment: Thank's for your answer. When I say that I wan't to usr the scroll wheel, i mean to use it horizontaly.